# using $http in component module angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components

I'd like to understand why i can't retrieve data from external sources.
I need to recover the content of a Json and parse it to display content in this template :

Nombre of news: {{new.length}}

```
<div>
    <lignevin class="ligne-vin" ng-repeat="new in $ctrl.news">
        <etiquevin class="etiquettevin">
            <img class="etiquette" src="{{new.img}}"/>
        </etiquevin>
        <descriptifvin class="descriptif-vin">
            <p class="title">{{new.name}}</p>
            <p class="sub-title">{{new.ref}}</p>
            <p>{{new.prixTotal}}</p>
            <p>{{new.prixUnit}}</p>
        </descriptifvin>
    </lignevin>
</div>
```

when i use this code it doesn't work and without any messages:

```
function NewsListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://myndd/myfile.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.news = data;
        console.log($scope);
    });
};

angular.
    module('myApp').
    component('newsList',{
        templateUrl :'templates/newsdetail.html',
        controller: NewsListCtrl,
        bindings: {
            news: '='
        }
    }
);
```

but if do not call the data from external like this : it works

```
angular.
    module('myApp').
    component('newsList',{
        templateUrl :'templates/newsdetail.html',
        controller: function NewsListCtrl(){
            this.news=[
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "name1",
                    "ref": "ref1",
                    "conditionnement" : "cond1",
                    "prixTotal": "10,00€",
                    "prixUnit" : "1,00€",
                    "img": "http://myndd/myfile1.png"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "name2",
                    "ref": ref2",
                    "conditionnement" : "cond2",
                    "prixTotal": "20,00",
                    "prixUnit" : "2,00€",
                    "img":"http://myndd/myfile2.png"
                }
            ];
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you show us the result of console.log($scope.news) after '$http.get' ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry i found my answer by trying one last thing right after posting this.
My mystake was in the loop in the template:

```
<lignevin class="ligne-vin" ng-repeat="new in news">
```